# SQL Server 2016 exclude results in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables: Report and Item.They are linked via reportID column.
What I am trying to do is to select all the reports that are in rejected state although all the items from the report are in approved state. I did the below query but this one is returning a line for each item that is in accepted state, but I checked in app and for these reports there are rejected items also.

```
select r.reportID
from Report r with(nolock)
inner join Item i with(nolock)
    on r.reportid = i.reportid
where
    (conditions for report to be in rejected state) and
    (conditions for items to be in approved state)
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: "select all the reports that are in rejected state although all the items from the report are in **rejected**" you mean "select all the reports that are in rejected state although all the items from the report are in **approved** state"?

Comment: What a messy question. Please see how to post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I meant approved status for the items, I received the answer below, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in all the reports that are in the **rejected** state although all the items from the report are in the **approved** state then use `NOT EXISTS` as follows

```
select r.reportID
from Report r
where r.state = 'rejected' and NOT EXISTS
(
   select 1
   from Item i
   where  r.reportid = i.reportid and i.state != 'approved'
)
```

The above code will return also reports without items at all.

Comment: I don't understand this:
    select 1
    from Item i on r.reportid = i.reportid
Should this be a where condition?

Comment: @99LittleBugsInTheCode true, corrected. Copy + paste error ... :)